# Problems starting artifactory on Debian

Tags: debian, startup

I've installed Artifactory on a Debian server with the standard provided deb package.

It has been installed for months, and has gone through a couple of upgrades, but throughout all that time, I've had constant problems with starting and stopping the artifactory service.

Right now, I'm attempting to reboot the server to collect some fresh log messages, and systemd is holding up the shutdown process (spinning at 100% CPU).  I assume it is related as I've not seen that kind of problem on any other of my (proxmox container) VMs (which are all pretty much the same).

I waited 5 minutes for systemd to get past whatever it was doing,
and then opened GDB on the host machine and attached to the process.

This is the stacktrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f179ad009a3 in __fxstat64 () from target:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f179aa9790e in chase_symlinks () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#2  0x00007f179aae9a69 in ?? () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#3  0x00007f179aae9c0d in ?? () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#4  0x00007f179aaea076 in unit_file_find_dropin_paths () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#5  0x000055a69fdf0ff8 in ?? ()
#6  0x000055a69fdf44e1 in ?? ()
#7  0x000055a69fe38b88 in ?? ()
#8  0x000055a69fe513e2 in ?? ()
#9  0x000055a69fde2d08 in ?? ()
#10 0x000055a69fe4bba2 in ?? ()
#11 0x000055a69fe70682 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f179aa2c6ff in ?? () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#13 0x00007f179aa33f84 in ?? () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#14 0x00007f179aa34478 in ?? () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#15 0x00007f179aa04e20 in ?? () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#16 0x00007f179aa05111 in sd_event_dispatch () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#17 0x00007f179aa052d8 in sd_event_run () from target:/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-241.so
#18 0x000055a69fe85fc3 in ?? ()
#19 0x000055a69fdddc06 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007f179ac3b09b in __libc_start_main () from target:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#21 0x000055a69fddf12a in ?? ()
```

I `kill -9 systemd_PID` and the VM (container) shuts down.
I bring the VM back up again, and this is the log from `journalctl -u artifactory`

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2023-02-22 22:07:12 AWST, end at Thu 2023-03-02 13:55:01 AWST. --
Mar 02 13:23:15 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
Mar 02 13:23:21 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:20.976Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:90       ] [main] - Starting Artifactory tomcat as user artifactory...                                                                                   
Mar 02 13:23:21 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:21.341Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1604       ] [main] - Checking open files and processes limits                                                                                             
Mar 02 13:23:21 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:21.773Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1607       ] [main] - Current max open files is 1024                                                                                                       
Mar 02 13:23:22 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:22.195Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1618       ] [main] - Current max open processes is 256881                                                                                                 
Mar 02 13:23:22 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: yaml validation succeeded
Mar 02 13:23:23 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:22.847Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:2975       ] [main] - System.yaml validation succeeded                                                                                                     
Mar 02 13:23:23 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: Database connection check failed Could not determine database type
Mar 02 13:23:25 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:24.709Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3475       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_ID to mxrapservers                                                                                            
Mar 02 13:23:25 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:25.697Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3475       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_IP to 10.0.0.3                                                                                                
Mar 02 13:23:26 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:26.534Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3475       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME to mxrapservers                                                                                          
Mar 02 13:23:29 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:29.588Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:221      ] [main] - Using Tomcat template to generate : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml                                    
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.407Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.port||8081} to default value : 8081                                                                           
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.463Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false                                            
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.513Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.relaxedPathChars||_SQUARE_BRACKETS_} to default value : _SQUARE_BRACKETS_                    
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.567Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.relaxedQueryChars||_SQUARE_BRACKETS_} to default value : _SQUARE_BRACKETS_                   
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.657Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||200} to default value : 200                                                      
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.789Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.port||8091} to default value : 8091                                               
Mar 02 13:23:30 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:30.858Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.maxThreads||5} to default value : 5                                               
Mar 02 13:23:31 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:31.146Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.acceptCount||5} to default value : 5                                              
Mar 02 13:23:32 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:32.709Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.http.port||8040} to default value : 8040
Mar 02 13:23:33 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:33.592Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false
Mar 02 13:23:34 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:34.441Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||50} to default value : 50
Mar 02 13:23:36 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:35.881Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:612       ] [main] - Resolved JF_PRODUCT_HOME (/opt/jfrog/artifactory) from environment variable
Mar 02 13:23:37 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:37.343Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${shared.tomcat.workDir||/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat} to default value : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat
Mar 02 13:23:38 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: tr: write error: Broken pipe
Mar 02 13:23:38 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: tr: write error
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: ========================
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF Environment variables
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: ========================
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_SHARED_NODE_ID                   : mxrapservers
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_SHARED_NODE_IP                   : 10.0.0.3
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_ARTIFACTORY_PID                  : /var/run/artifactory.pid
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_SYSTEM_YAML                      : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_PRODUCT_HOME                     : /opt/jfrog/artifactory
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES : jfrt,jfac,jfmd,jffe,jfob,jfint,jfevt
Mar 02 13:23:45 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME                 : mxrapservers
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers crontab[3871]: (root) LIST (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers crontab[3873]: (root) REPLACE (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers crontab[3887]: (root) LIST (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers crontab[3886]: (root) REPLACE (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers su[3921]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers su[3921]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers su[3921]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers su[3921]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Mar 02 13:23:49 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[188]: 2023-03-02T05:23:49.579Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:612       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.script.serviceStartTimeout (180) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Mar 02 13:24:45 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 02 13:24:45 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Mar 02 13:24:45 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 02 13:24:45 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:24:45 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 4.597s CPU time.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Service RestartSec=1min expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 4.597s CPU time.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[6033]: 2023-03-02T05:25:46.548Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:88       ] [main] - Artifactory Tomcat already started
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Can't open PID file /run/artifactory.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:25:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 359ms CPU time.
Mar 02 13:26:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Service RestartSec=1min expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 13:26:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mar 02 13:26:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:26:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 359ms CPU time.
Mar 02 13:26:46 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
Mar 02 13:26:47 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[7145]: 2023-03-02T05:26:47.067Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:88       ] [main] - Artifactory Tomcat already started
Mar 02 13:26:47 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Can't open PID file /run/artifactory.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 02 13:26:47 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 02 13:26:47 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:26:47 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 382ms CPU time.
```

Each minute the same messages repeat themselves,
until I run `killall java`
SNIP

```
Mar 02 13:43:55 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Service RestartSec=1min expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 13:43:55 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 19.
Mar 02 13:43:55 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:43:55 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 356ms CPU time.
Mar 02 13:43:55 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
Mar 02 13:43:56 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[26292]: 2023-03-02T05:43:56.044Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:88       ] [main] - Artifactory Tomcat already started
Mar 02 13:43:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Can't open PID file /run/artifactory.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 02 13:43:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 02 13:43:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:43:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 345ms CPU time.
Mar 02 13:44:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Service RestartSec=1min expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 13:44:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 20.
Mar 02 13:44:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:44:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 345ms CPU time.
Mar 02 13:45:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Service RestartSec=1min expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 13:45:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 21.
Mar 02 13:45:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Mar 02 13:45:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Consumed 359ms CPU time.
Mar 02 13:45:56 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.037Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:90       ] [main] - Starting Artifactory tomcat as user artifactory...                                                                                       
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.073Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1604       ] [main] - Checking open files and processes limits                                                                                                 
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.089Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1607       ] [main] - Current max open files is 1024                                                                                                           
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.104Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1618       ] [main] - Current max open processes is 256881                                                                                                     
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: yaml validation succeeded
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.133Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:2975       ] [main] - System.yaml validation succeeded                                                                                                         
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Database connection check failed Could not determine database type
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.230Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3475       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_ID to mxrapservers                                                                                                
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.281Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3475       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_IP to 10.0.0.3                                                                                                    
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.329Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3475       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME to mxrapservers                                                                                              
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.486Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:221      ] [main] - Using Tomcat template to generate : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml                                        
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.569Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.port||8081} to default value : 8081                                                                               
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.619Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false                                                
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.669Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.relaxedPathChars||_SQUARE_BRACKETS_} to default value : _SQUARE_BRACKETS_                        
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.719Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.relaxedQueryChars||_SQUARE_BRACKETS_} to default value : _SQUARE_BRACKETS_                       
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.769Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||200} to default value : 200                                                          
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.852Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.port||8091} to default value : 8091                                                   
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.901Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.maxThreads||5} to default value : 5                                                   
Mar 02 13:45:57 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:57.951Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.acceptCount||5} to default value : 5                                                  
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:58.041Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.http.port||8040} to default value : 8040    
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:58.091Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:58.142Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||50} to default value : 50
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:58.244Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:612       ] [main] - Resolved JF_PRODUCT_HOME (/opt/jfrog/artifactory) from environment variable
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:45:58.361Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:972       ] [main] - Resolved ${shared.tomcat.workDir||/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat} to default value : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: tr: write error: Broken pipe
Mar 02 13:45:58 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: tr: write error
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: ========================
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF Environment variables
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: ========================
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_SHARED_NODE_ID                   : mxrapservers
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_SHARED_NODE_IP                   : 10.0.0.3
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_ARTIFACTORY_PID                  : /var/run/artifactory.pid
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_SYSTEM_YAML                      : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_PRODUCT_HOME                     : /opt/jfrog/artifactory
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES : jfrt,jfac,jfmd,jffe,jfob,jfint,jfevt
Mar 02 13:45:59 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME                 : mxrapservers
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers crontab[31888]: (root) LIST (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers crontab[31890]: (root) REPLACE (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers crontab[31896]: (root) LIST (artifactory)
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers su[31930]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers su[31930]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers su[31930]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers su[31930]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Mar 02 13:46:00 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:46:00.273Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:612       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.script.serviceStartTimeout (180) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Mar 02 13:47:00 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:47:00.765Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:132      ] [main] - Artifactory Tomcat started in normal mode
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: 2023-03-02T05:47:01.189Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:950      ] [main] - Artifactory running with PID 32010
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers su[33412]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers su[33412]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers su[33412]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Using default router's certificate and private key
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Starting router...
Mar 02 13:47:01 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: router not running. Proceed to start it up.
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: router started. PID: 33520
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33412]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33522]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33522]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33522]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Starting metadata...
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: JF_METADATA_ACCESSCLIENT_URL: http://localhost:8081/access
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: metadata started. PID: 33653
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33522]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33655]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33655]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers su[33655]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:47:02 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Starting frontend...
Mar 02 13:47:03 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: frontend not running. Proceed to start it up.
Mar 02 13:47:04 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: frontend started. PID: 33776
Mar 02 13:47:04 mxrapservers su[33778]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:47:04 mxrapservers su[33778]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:47:04 mxrapservers su[33778]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:47:04 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Starting observability...
Mar 02 13:47:04 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: observability not running. Proceed to start it up.
Mar 02 13:47:06 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: observability started. PID: 33900
Mar 02 13:47:06 mxrapservers su[33902]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:47:06 mxrapservers su[33902]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:47:06 mxrapservers su[33902]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:47:06 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Starting integration...
Mar 02 13:47:06 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: PID exists (12591), but integration not running. Proceed to start it up.
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: integration started. PID: 34027
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers su[33902]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers su[34029]: (to artifactory) root on none
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers su[34029]: pam_limits(su:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=1024, hard=524288: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers su[34029]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: Starting event...
Mar 02 13:47:08 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: PID exists (12715), but event not running. Proceed to start it up.
Mar 02 13:47:09 mxrapservers artifactoryManage.sh[28584]: event started. PID: 34147
Mar 02 13:47:10 mxrapservers systemd[1]: Started Artifactory service.
```

And now the server is running and appears to be happy.

Any ideas?  Why can't artifactory start by itself?

Interesting (perhaps), is after I shut down the service, I was able to `systemctl start artifactory` and it started up without issues.

Comment: Which Debian are you using ?

Comment: Debian Buster
Linux version 5.15.85-1-pve (build@proxmox) (gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP PVE 5.15.85-1 (2023-02-01T00:00Z)
jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce 7.55.2 (there is an update waiting: 7.55.3, I'll pin it to .2 while this question is active)